# Is there a way to specify all columns but pick one of a duplicate column when joining data?

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a T-SQL query that looks (example) like this:

```
Select * 
into #temptable 
from tablex
inner join tabley y on y.name = x.name
inner join tablez z on z.name = y.name
```

both table X and table Z have a column called `ID`. Is there a way to specify which version of column ID I want without listing every column in place of the * ?

Comment: y.*, z.*  i think is what your asking or  y.id as yid, z.id as zid

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "which version I want".   Is it based on a logical rule, or your momentary whim, or something else?

Comment: No. But you can always ignore the unwanted column if you don't need it in whatever is receiving your data. And they are not different "versions" of a column, they are different columns, from different tables. Based on your query, they presumably represent different things and may have different values, since they're not part of the key for the join, so this is not even a case of removing columns which duplicate the same information. BTW unless your "name" fields are immutable, they're potentially a bad candidate for a join operation.

Comment: You shouldn't be using select * in the first place. You should get in the habit of always specifying the columns you want returned.